# ListView displays data twice

Tags: android, database, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am working on a small application to save the data of the book (such as the name of the book, the type of the book, the author of the book and the year of publication) in a database, but when the data is returned from the databases using **CursorLoader** It's shown twice in **ListView**

> This is a code of **AddBook** activity.

```
package training.android.com.librarycard;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import training.android.com.librarycard.Database.Database;
import training.android.com.librarycard.Database.LibraryCardContract;

public class AddBook extends AppCompatActivity
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int EXISTING_BOOK_LOADER = 0;
    Spinner mBookType;
    EditText mBookTitle, mBookAuthor, mBookPublishYear;
    String bookType;
    int position;
    private boolean bookHasChanged = false;

    private Uri currentBookUri;

    private View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            bookHasChanged = true;
            return false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_book);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null) {
            currentBookUri = intent.getData();

            if (currentBookUri == null) {
                setTitle("Add a book");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else {
                setTitle("Edit a book");
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_BOOK_LOADER, null, this);
            }

        }

        mBookType = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mBookTitle = findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        mBookAuthor = findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        mBookPublishYear = findViewById(R.id.publish_year);

        mBookType.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        mBookAuthor.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        mBookTitle.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        mBookPublishYear.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);


        setupBookTypeSpinner();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (currentBookUri == null) {
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.action_save:
                setBook();
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (!bookHasChanged) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(AddBook.this);
                    return true;
                }
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener
                        = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(AddBook.this);
                    }
                };

                showUnsavedChangeDialog(discardButtonClickListener);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showUnsavedChangeDialog(DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Discard your changes and quit editing?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Discard", discardButtonClickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Keep editing", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (dialog != null)
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    private void showDeleteConfirmationDialog() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Delete this book ?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                deleteBook();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (dialog != null)
                    dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void deleteBook() {
        if (currentBookUri != null) {
            int rowDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(currentBookUri, null, null);
            if (rowDeleted == 0)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Delete book failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, "Delete book successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        finish();

    }


    public void setupBookTypeSpinner() {
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> bookTypeAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.books_type, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        bookTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        mBookType.setAdapter(bookTypeAdapter);

        mBookType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bookType = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                position = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Log.i("BookTypeSelection", bookType+"");

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void setBook() {
        String bookTitle = mBookTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String bookAuthor = mBookAuthor.getText().toString().trim();
        String publishYear = mBookPublishYear.getText().toString().trim();

        if (currentBookUri == null && TextUtils.isEmpty(bookTitle) && TextUtils.isEmpty(bookAuthor)
                 && TextUtils.isEmpty(publishYear))
            return;

        Database database = new Database(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE, bookTitle);
        values.put(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_AUTHOR, bookAuthor);
        values.put(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_PUBLISH_YEAR, publishYear);
        values.put(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TYPE, bookType);

        if (currentBookUri == null) {
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.CONTENT_URI, values);
            if (uri == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Book saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            int rowAffected = getContentResolver().update(currentBookUri, values, null, null);
            if (rowAffected == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error with saving book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Book saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        db.insert(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert new book", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String [] projection = {
                LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE,
                LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TYPE,
                LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_AUTHOR,
                LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_PUBLISH_YEAR };
        return new CursorLoader(this,currentBookUri,projection,
                null,null,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if(data.moveToFirst()){
            String title = data.getString(
                    data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE));
            String type = data.getString(
                    data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TYPE));
            String publishYear = data.getString(
                    data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_PUBLISH_YEAR));
            String author = data.getString(
                    data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_AUTHOR));

            mBookTitle.setText(title);
            mBookAuthor.setText(author);
            mBookType.setSelection(position);
            mBookPublishYear.setText(publishYear);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mBookTitle.setText("");
        mBookType.setSelection(position);
        mBookAuthor.setText("");
        mBookPublishYear.setText("");

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!bookHasChanged){
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener =
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                };

        showUnsavedChangeDialog(discardButtonClickListener);
    }





}
```

> And this is a code of **Home** activity that contains a **listView** to
>   display the data.

```
   package training.android.com.librarycard;

    import android.app.LoaderManager;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.CursorLoader;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.Loader;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import training.android.com.librarycard.Database.Database;
    import training.android.com.librarycard.Database.LibraryCardContract;
    import training.android.com.librarycard.Models.BookCursorAdapter;
    import training.android.com.librarycard.Models.BookDetail;

    public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        private static final int BOOK_LOADER = 0;
        private ListView mBookList;
        private BookCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            mBookList = findViewById(R.id.books_rv);

            cursorAdapter = new BookCursorAdapter(this, null);
            mBookList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

            mBookList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, AddBook.class);
                    Uri currentPetUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.CONTENT_URI, id);
                    intent.setData(currentPetUri);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            getLoaderManager().initLoader(BOOK_LOADER, null, this);


            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddBook.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.delete_all_books:
                    deleteAllBooks();
                    return true;
            }

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        private void deleteAllBooks() {
            int rowDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.CONTENT_URI,
                    null, null);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();


            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            String[] projection = {
                    LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard._ID,
                    LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE,
                    LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_AUTHOR,
                    LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TYPE,
                    LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_PUBLISH_YEAR};

            return new CursorLoader(this, LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            cursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);

        }


    }

> This is a code of **BookCursorAdapter** class.
package training.android.com.librarycard.Models;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import training.android.com.librarycard.Database.LibraryCardContract;
import training.android.com.librarycard.R;

/**
 * Created by Hassan on 4/9/2018.
 */

public class BookCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public BookCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.book_list,parent,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView bookTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.book_name_tv);
        TextView bookAuthor = view.findViewById(R.id.author_tv);
        TextView bookType = view.findViewById(R.id.book_type_tv);
        TextView publishYear = view.findViewById(R.id.publish_year_tv);

        String title = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TITLE));
        String type = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_TYPE));
        String year = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_PUBLISH_YEAR));
        String author = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(LibraryCardContract.LibraryCard.COLUMN_BOOK_AUTHOR));


        bookAuthor.setText(author);
        bookTitle.setText(title);
        bookType.setText(type);
        publishYear.setText(year);



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }
}
```

> Screenshot of the application
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASy40.png)